# Poisson process to determine request arrival times in LTE network

Tags: poisson-distribution, simulation, random-generation

I need some help with this problem.

A Poisson process is generally used to describe the arrival of calls in a mobile network. Since I am developing a simulator for LTE, i need to implement such a process to realistically randomize the entry requests of users wishing to connect.

After reading about the Poisson process I still can't reach a simple solution just to return the arrival times of each request - such as: "new users will try to connect on seconds: 3, 10, 20, 24" - given the average arrival rate and the simulation duration.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you clarify this? What is it you need exactly? Are you wondering what a Poisson process is? Are you wondering how to code one?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering how to code it, namely on Matlab. Lets suppose I am running a simulation for 1000 seconds. My problem here is, given a certain arrival rate, getting the arriving times for new calls along those 1000 seconds: as in, on seconds 6, 13, 15, whatever, following a poisson distribution. Am I being clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go would to be to recognize that a Poisson process has exponentially distributed inter-arrival times with a mean parameter the same as the Poisson average rate. I believe the `exprnd` function in MATLAB can generate such exponentially-distributed data. Just generate a long list of such data, and calculate the cumulative sums to get arrival times.

Comment: This solved it, thank you! I didn't realize the correspondence between the poisson process and the exponential distributed inter-arrival times